# Is the address of a std::optional's value stable?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, std, c++17

Say I have a `std::optional<T>`. I reset and assign the value multiple times. Is the address of the value (when present) always the same for a given optional?

In other words:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <optional>
#include <string>

template<typename T>
auto test()
{
    auto opt = std::optional<T>{T{}};
    auto* ptr = &*opt;

    opt.reset();
    opt = T{};

    assert(ptr == &*opt); // Can this assert fail?
}

int main()
{
    test<int>();
    test<double>();
    test<std::string>();
    // ...
}
```

Does the standard guarantee the stability of the address of the value?

Comment: Relevant part of the standard: http://eel.is/c++draft/optional

Comment: I don't see anything that would require the object to stay in the same location, that is, it seems like a complying implementation could have `sizeof(std::optional<T>) >= 2*sizeof(T)` and shift the location of the object. But no sane implementation would do that

Comment: @Justin Thanks for the links! Indeed, I want to store a pointer to the value somewhere (a C library needs the address of my value). I can make sure that the optional does have value, when the C library accesses the pointer. "No sane implementation" puts it nicely :-)

Comment: Wouldn't this be checking the address of an object after its lifetime has ended?

Comment: @krzaq It's allowed: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lifetime#Storage_reuse

Comment: @Justin right, thanks!

Comment: Your example has UB: the initial `*opt` on an unengaged optional

Comment: @Barry Thanks, fixed by initializing with T{}.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> Does the standard guarantee the stability of the address of the value?

From my point of view, it is *unspecified* whether the address is stable or not.

Formally, the standard only guarantees that there are no dynamic allocations for the object contained within `std::optional` and the containing object is stored as a part of `std::optional`:

> 23.6.3 Class template optional [optional.optional]
>
> Any instance of optional at any given time either contains a value
>   or does not contain a value. *When an instance of optional contains
>   a value, it means that an object of type T, referred to as the
>   optional object’s contained value, is allocated within the storage of
>   the optional object. Implementations are not permitted to use
>   additional storage, such as dynamic memory, to allocate its contained
>   value. The contained value shall be allocated in a region of the
>   optional storage suitably aligned for the type T.* When an object of
>   type optional is contextually converted to bool, the conversion
>   returns true if the object contains a value; otherwise the conversion
>   returns false.

The actual storage mechanism is defined by a particular implementation, so, potentially, the address might change.

In practice, however, implementations will be using something like `aligned_storage` (see *boost* [implementation](https://github.com/boostorg/optional/blob/develop/include/boost/optional/optional.hpp)) or `union` (as *gcc* [does](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-7.3.0/libstdc++/api/a01010_source.html)) and keep an address of the containing object the same.

Comment: As an aside, a `union` is the only possible implementation (barring magic of course) due to the `constexpr` requirements of `std::optional`.

Comment: Im having issues with it